# How to remove spaces between a Linearlayout and relativeLayout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following code in my thanks_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#00868B" >

           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/thanks_message"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />
            
           <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/thanks_message"
           android:text="Go To Giveaway Page" /> 
                   
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/button1" 
               android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >
        
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>
     
 </RelativeLayout>
```

For this code I have the following output :

[image]

here a lot of spaces is available between the button having text "Go to Giveaway Page" and "Button" . Why ? I do not want this spaces . How can I remove this spaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `android:layout_marginTop="45dp"` from your LinearLayout

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#00868B" >

           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/thanks_message"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView" />

           <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/thanks_message"
           android:text="Go To Giveaway Page" /> 

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/button1" 
             >

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```